# Load TorchScript model exported by Python in LibTorch via std::istream

Tags: c++, pytorch, jit, libtorch

I have exported a standard pretrained PyTorch model in Python with the following code:

```py
import torch
import torchvision

model = torchvision.models.resnext50_32x4d(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save("traced_resnext50_32x4d_model.pt")
```

I am now trying to load this model via the `Module torch::jit::load(std::istream &in, c10::optional<c10::Device> device = c10::nullopt)` function of LibTorch.

It takes an `std::istream` and I have the .pt model loaded as simple `const char*` buffer with a size. Since `strstreambuf` is deprecated, I needed to use a custom streambuf:

```cpp
class MemReader : public std::streambuf {
public:
    MemReader(const char* data, size_t size);
 
private:
    int_type underflow();
    int_type uflow();
    int_type pbackfail(int_type ch);
    std::streamsize showmanyc();
 
    const char* const begin_;
    const char* const end_;
    const char* current_;
};

MemReader::MemReader(const char* data, size_t size) : 
    begin_(data), 
    end_(data + size), 
    current_(data) 
{}
 
MemReader::int_type MemReader::underflow() {
    if (current_ == end_) {
        return traits_type::eof();
    }
    return traits_type::to_int_type(*current_);
}
 
MemReader::int_type MemReader::uflow() {
    if (current_ == end_) {
        return traits_type::eof();
    }
    return traits_type::to_int_type(*current_++);
}
 
MemReader::int_type MemReader::pbackfail(int_type ch) {
    if (current_ == begin_ || (ch != traits_type::eof() && ch != current_[-1])) {
        return traits_type::eof();
    }
    return traits_type::to_int_type(*--current_);
}
 
std::streamsize MemReader::showmanyc() {
    return end_ - current_;
}
```

I verified that the `.pt` model file and my `MemReader mr` wrapped in an `std::istream(&mr)` both contain the ***exact same data***.

However, when loading the model with this code:

```cpp
utils::MemReader mr(modelScript, modelScriptSize);
std::istream is(&mr);
mod_ = torch::jit::load(is, device_);
```

I get this error:

```
istream reader failed: checking archive.
Exception raised from validate at /tmp/pytorch/pytorch/caffe2/serialize/istream_adapter.cc:32 (most recent call first):
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) + 0x6c (0x7fdce0d4c7ac in /usr/local/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10::detail::torchCheckFail(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) + 0xfa (0x7fdce0d18866 in /usr/local/lib/libc10.so)
frame #2: caffe2::serialize::IStreamAdapter::validate(char const*) const + 0x17b (0x7fdce3635beb in /usr/local/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #3: caffe2::serialize::IStreamAdapter::read(unsigned long, void*, unsigned long, char const*) const + 0x41 (0x7fdce3635d21 in /usr/local/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x3f9c02b (0x7fdce4d2402b in /usr/local/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #5: torch::jit::load(std::shared_ptr<caffe2::serialize::ReadAdapterInterface>, c10::optional<c10::Device>, std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&) + 0x6c (0x7fdce4d20a5c in /usr/local/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #6: torch::jit::load(std::istream&, c10::optional<c10::Device>, std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&) + 0xc2 (0x7fdce4d22aa2 in /usr/local/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
frame #7: torch::jit::load(std::istream&, c10::optional<c10::Device>) + 0x6a (0x7fdce4d22b8a in /usr/local/lib/libtorch_cpu.so)
```

I know about the fact you need to trace the model with the same PyTorch version as your LibTorch version. But when I load the model via file path:

```cpp
mod_ = torch::jit::load("/data/bin/traced_resnext50_32x4d_model.pt", device_);
```

It works!

Anybody know whats up here?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my `MemReader` now with the deprecated `std::strstreambuf`  and now it works. Although they produce the same output when reading via `get(char)`, something must be different between them.

I do not know enough C++ to tell what exactly was the issue here.